# using Cayley Hamilton to find a power of linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

I have reached the the following formula using Cayley Hamilton:

$$T^3-2T+2I=0$$

Now I need to find $T^4$ so what I did is $T(T^3-2T+2I=0)\iff T^4-2T^2+2IT=0\iff T^4=2T^2-2IT$

But the answer is $T^4=2T^2-2T$ why isn't it $-2IT$?

Comment: For any linear transformation (square matrix) $L$, the identity times $L$ is $L$ itself. I.e. $L*I=I*L=L$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer:

$I$ is the identity operator, so $IT=T$ for all operators $T$.